# Line up nested div tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css

Please have a look at the image below.  I'm trying to remove the white space in between the images on the left.  Each of the images are in a div tag.  My CSS is located after the image.

[image: I'm trying to get these div tags to come up next to eachother]

```
div.Forum {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 36px;
}

div.Forum div 
{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  clear: none; 
}

div.ForumChild 
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 228px;
    height:auto;
    padding: 12px 12px 10px 10px;
    margin: auto auto;    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.ForumChild img {
    width: 226px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 2px;

}
```

The Forum class is the parent and the ForumChild class is used for each of the images.  Here is the HTML.  It's created in a Razor View.

```
<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {                                
                    <div class="ForumChild">                   
                      <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />

                      <br />

                    </div>
            }
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

I updated my code to the following to resolve my issue. Thanks everyone!

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    int counter = 0;   
}


<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>
        @for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            <div class="ForumChild">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (counter % 3 == z)
                    {
                        <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />

                    }
                    counter++;
                }               
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, sorry, but it looks like you are mistaken as to what the alt tag on an image is for. It is meant to describe the image so screen readers know what the image is, whereas you think it is used as text if the img isn't found. if you are storing a description of the image somewhere, I would recommend using that as the alt information

Comment: Your div.Forum `margin` is useless without `width`, you can delete it. And you can use shorthand for padding like: `padding:0 36px`. And try `display:inline` for div.Forum div.

Comment: @qeremy Thanks. I removed margin and shorthanded my padding.  The display:inline didn't have any visible effect though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all whitespace between images like you want, `float` won't work. You could create three *column* `<div>` tags and place your images within those columns. For instance, if you want three columns:

HTML:

```
<div class="imgCol">
    <!-- every third image -->
</div>
<div class="imgCol">
    <!-- every third image -->
</div>
<div class="imgCol">
    <!-- every third image -->
</div>
```

Then, add `float: left;` to the CSS for your column class (in this case `.imgCol`) and ensure the widths and margins are such that the columns appear side by side and no float drop occurs.

Here's a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/yLRWK/**

For your particular situation, you could implement this as follows. I don't code in ASP.net, so there is some pseudocode thrown in

```
<div class="Forum">
    <p>The Forum</p>
    <div class="imgCol">
        /* create counter = 0 */
        @foreach (var item in Model) {                           
            /* if counter % 3 == 0, then write img tag */     
            <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
            /* counter++ */
        }
    </div>
    <div class="imgCol">
        /* create counter = 0 */
        @foreach (var item in Model) {                           
            /* if counter % 3 == 1, then write img tag */     
            <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
            /* counter++ */
        }
    </div>
    <div class="imgCol">
        /* create counter = 0 */
        @foreach (var item in Model) {                           
            /* if counter % 3 == 2, then write img tag */     
            <img src="@item.Blog.Image.img_path" alt="Not Found" />
            /* counter++ */
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

There may be a better solution that does not require looping through the images three times, but that is best left to someone that better knows ASP.net

Comment: This worked well!  I updated my question with what I did.  I love that demo site btw.  Thanks again